# Get image of an item using its id - Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to get user data from its facebook login. I have this following information from the users login

```
"favorite_teams":
        [
            {"id":"7724542745","name":"Manchester United"},
            {"id":"12254981412","name":"McLaren"},
            {"id":"190313434323691","name":"Indian Cricket Team"},
            {"id":"495700570474595","name":"Manchester United\" The Comeback Kings"},
            {"id":"153516655618","name":"Royal Challengers Bangalore"}
        ],
```

I would like to show some images along with the names. Is it possible to get images using the id ? If yes, can you please help me out ?
Thanks :)

Comment: yes you can get images through id

Comment: https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-find-parse-users-that-are-facebook-friends-with-the-current-user
try this link

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by _show some images along with the names_. Show what pictures? From the Page's albums, their profile, their cover or something else? If you mean from their albums, go to the Graph API explorer and type: `7724542745/?fields=albums` after the -->/v2.2/. This will give you the albums for the ManU Page ID in this case. IF you mean their Profile, type: `7724542745/picture` and `7724542745?fields=cover` for the Page cover.

Comment: @SiddharthLele I mean the images of the teams for eg Image of Manchester United.

Comment: @Droider: So query the _albums_ tag for the respective pages using the syntax `REPLACE_THE_PAGE_ID/?fields=albums` and then parse through the result.

Comment: @SiddharthLele some code would be of great help as I just started to work on facebook sdk

Comment: @Droider: I will have to dig up some old code for that. I haven't worked on the FB SDK since it was v2.x something. :-(. But if no one has answered until I come back from lunch, I will cook some code up for ya. ;-)

Comment: @SiddharthLele thanks a lot for your support